# Recursive programming stump?

Tags: python

I was asked to create a program, after i was done i was to make a recursive version of it.
Its nothing much, it laces strings together. Here is the version of it that i wrote, can anyone tell me how to make a recursive program out of this?

```
def laceStrings(s1, s2):
    """
    s1 and s2 are strings.

    Returns a new str with elements of s1 and s2 interlaced,
    beginning with s1. If strings are not of same length, 
    then the extra elements should appear at the end.
    """
    join = []
    smaller = min(s1, s2, key=len)
    for num in range(len(smaller)):
        join.append(s1[num])
        join.append(s2[num])
    join = ''.join(join)
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        smaller = len(smaller)
        join = join + max(s1, s2, key=len)[smaller:]
    return join
```

Edit: My friend gave me this template, but i still cant figure out out. Can anyone help?

```
def laceStringsRecur(s1, s2):
    """
    s1 and s2 are strings.

    Returns a new str with elements of s1 and s2 interlaced,
    beginning with s1. If strings are not of same length, 
    then the extra elements should appear at the end.
    """
    def helpLaceStrings(s1, s2, out):
        if s1 == '':
            #PLACE A LINE OF CODE HERE
        if s2 == '':
            #PLACE A LINE OF CODE HERE
        else:
            #PLACE A LINE OF CODE HERE
    return helpLaceStrings(s1, s2, '')
```

Comment: I think this is a perfectly acceptable question.  thg435's answer shows it is quite answerable.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)):

> A recursive function definition has one or more base cases, meaning input(s) for which the function produces a result trivially (without recurring), and one or more recursive cases, meaning input(s) for which the program recurs (calls itself).

Here, the base case is the following (assuming A and B are arguments strings):

```
 if one of A or B is empty -> return the other string
```

and the recursive case:

```
   split each of A, B into the first char and the rest (eg. XYZ => X, YZ)
   (recursive call) S = interlaced version of rest(A),rest(B)
   return first-char(A) + first-char(B) + S
```

Let us know if you have problems translating this to python.

Answer (score 6):

```
def laceStringsRecur(s1, s2):

    """
    s1 and s2 are strings.

    Returns a new str with elements of s1 and s2 interlaced,
    beginning with s1. If strings are not of same length, 
    then the extra elements should appear at the end.
    """
    def helpLaceStrings(s1, s2, out):
        if s1 == '':
            #PLACE A LINE OF CODE HERE
            return out+s2
        if s2 == '':
            #PLACE A LINE OF CODE HERE
            return out+s1
        else:
            #PLACE A LINE OF CODE HERE
            return helpLaceStrings(s1[1:], s2[1:], out+s1[0]+s2[0])
    return helpLaceStrings(s1, s2, '')
```